# How do you change a name mentioned multiple times in a region

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to know if there's shortcut to change a name like "tom" to "sally" in a region in Visual Studio 2013. I have about 40+ `tom`'s and to change it manually takes forever. I'm using vb.net. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ctrl+H is for Find and replace, Ctrl+R+R is for name replace

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a manual reading service. RTFM.

Answer (score -1):

Other than using a find and replace (CTRL+H), you can use a text editor like sublime text:

https://www.sublimetext.com/

Comment: I honestly don't know why this was down voted.  Please, provide feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can limit the replacement to a selected region of text.  In the Find/Replace dialog there is a "Look In" drop down.  If you have text selected, you will have the option "Selection"   It's only visible when you have selected text which is confusing/misleading (why not just disable?).

You can then use replace all, and the replacement will be limited to the selection region.

If you collapse a code region you can select the entire region easily.